# How it the concept of gradient in TensorFlow related to the mathematical definition of gradient?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, gradient

The [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) explains the
function

```
tf.gradients(
    ys,
    xs,
    grad_ys=None,
    name='gradients',
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=False,
    gate_gradients=False,
    aggregation_method=None,
    stop_gradients=None
)
```

saying:

- [it] constructs symbolic derivatives of sum of ys w.r.t. x in xs.
- ys and xs are each a Tensor or a list of tensors.
- gradients() adds ops to the graph to output the derivatives of ys with respect to xs.
- ys: A Tensor or list of tensors to be differentiated

I find it difficult to relate this with the mathematical definition of gradient. For example, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient), the **gradient** of a scalar function f(x1, x2, x3, ..., xn) is a vector field (i.e. a function grad f : Rn -> Rn) with certain properties involving the dot product of vectors. You can also speak about the gradient of f at a certain point: (grad f)(x1, x2, x3, ..., xn).

The TensorFlow documentation speaks about **tensors** instead of **vectors**: can the definition of gradient be generalized from functions that map vectors to scalars to functions that map tensors to scalars? Is there a dot product between tensors?

Even if the definition of gradient can be applied to functions f that map tensors to scalars (with the dot product in the definition working on tensors), the documentation speaks about differentiating **tensors** themselves: the parameter ys is a "Tensor or list of tensors to be differentiated". According to the documentation "Tensor is a multi-dimensional array used for computation", so a tensor is not a function, how can it be differentiated?

So, how is this concept of gradient in TensorFlow exactly related to the definition from wikipedia?

Comment: Of course there is a dot (inner) product between tensors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Tensors

Comment: @desertnaut: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

One would *expect* that the Tensorflow Gradient is simply the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), i.e. the derivative of a rank (*m*) tensor *Y* against a rank (*n*) tensor *X* is the rank (*m + n*) tensor comprised of each individual derivative ∂Y<sup>*j*<sub>1</sub>...*j*<sub>m</sub></sup>/∂X<sup>*i*<sub>1</sub>...*i*<sub>n</sub></sup>.

However, you may notice that the gradient isn't actually a rank (*m + n*) tensor, but rather always takes the rank *n* of the tensor *X* -- indeed, it appears that Tensorflow gives you the gradient of the scalar sum(*Y*) against *X*.

Of course, the real Jacobians are stored internally for calculation in applying the Chain rule.