# Where does Tensorflow store the *actual* Jacobians?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent, automatic-differentiation, autodiff

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088548/how-it-the-concept-of-gradient-in-tensorflow-related-to-the-mathematical-definit/62287422#62287422), Tensorflow's gradients are not true Jacobians -- the "gradient" of *Y* against *X* is actually just the gradient of sum(*Y*) against *X*. Similarly, Pytorch does not show Jacobians at all when the output is not a scalar.

But surely the full Jacobian is needed for computation (in the application of the chain rule).

Where, internally, is this stored? i.e. is there some object hidden within GradientTape that I can access?

Comment: In general, using aggregated gradients allows TensorFlow to make computations faster than having full Jacobians ([see this comment and thread in general for some insight from the devs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675#issuecomment-). 170271427). However, you can use [`tf.GradientTape.jacobian`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#jacobian) / [`tf.GradientTape.batch_jacobian`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#batch_jacobian) to get actual Jacobian matrices.

Comment: @jdehesa Wait, I don't understand: how can the aggregated gradients be used for computations? Surely the chain rule requires the actual Jacobians.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the link right, [this is the one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675#issuecomment-170271427). TensorFlow uses "reverse automatic differentiation" ([see here about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation), is the general term form [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)). With reverse AD, essentially you have to do a new computation for each output variable, so TensorFlow assumes that you want the gradient wrt the sum of targets (which is usually the case).

Comment: @jdehesa Um, so if you have some chain `x --> y --> z` where z is a scalar and y is a higher-rank tensor, am I correct in understanding that the derivative `gradient(z, x)` is calculated *not* using `gradient(y, x)` directly but using gradients of individual scalar parameters `gradient(y[1], x)` etc.? If that's the thing, I'm not sure I understand how this difference has to do with reverse vs forward AD.

Comment: As I understand it, if you want the Jacobian of `z` wrt `x`, in forward AD you would do a loop like `yd = gradient(y, x[0]); jacobian[:, i] = gradient(z, y) * yd`, so you would get one Jacobian column at a time. In reverse AD, you'd do `yd = gradient(z[i], y); jacobian[i, :] = gradient(y, x) * yd`, so you would be doing Jacobian rows. If you assume that `z` is scalar, then you can do the whole gradient in one pass with reverse AD, but not with forward AD.

Comment: But you're right that either forward or backward it would require a loop to build the Jacobian. But what I meant is TensorFlow does not have any "stored" Jacobian matrices internally because it never attempts to compute the gradient of the multidimensional output, it just does the summed one, which allows it to do it in one pass. It is not that it computes the Jacobian and then gives you the result of summing its rows.